# Some of the submenus disabled in applet

Tags: java, swing, browser, applet

My applet has a menu bar and some sub menus.When I access the applet from my systems browser,all sub menus are enabled but when I access same url from some other machine then some of the sub menus are disabled.
What can be the issue?

Do I need to do any changes in the settings  of the browser?

CODE SNIPPET

```
private void setupMenus() {
        getContentPane().add(mainMenuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');
        mainMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("new_doc")).setMnemonic('n');
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("open_doc")).setMnemonic('o');   //Disabled
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("save_doc")).setMnemonic('s');                fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("save_as")).setMnemonic('a');
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("export_doc")).setMnemonic('e'); //Disabled

        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("print")).setMnemonic('p');
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("print_all"));
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("close_doc")).setMnemonic('c');
        fileMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("close_all_doc")).setMnemonic('l');

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        editMenu.setMnemonic('e');
        mainMenuBar.add(editMenu);
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("undo")).setMnemonic('u');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("redo")).setMnemonic('r');
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("cut")).setMnemonic('t');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("copy")).setMnemonic('c');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("paste")).setMnemonic('p');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("delete")).setMnemonic('d');
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("selectAll")).setMnemonic('s');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("deselectAll")).setMnemonic('e');
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("selectArea")).setMnemonic('a');
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("preferences")).setMnemonic('f');

        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        viewMenu.setMnemonic('v');
        mainMenuBar.add(viewMenu);
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("page_first")).setMnemonic('f');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("page_prev")).setMnemonic('p');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("page_next")).setMnemonic('n');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("page_last")).setMnemonic('l');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("goto_page")).setMnemonic('g');
        viewMenu.addSeparator();
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("doc_first")).setMnemonic('i');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("doc_prev")).setMnemonic('r');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("doc_next")).setMnemonic('e');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("doc_last")).setMnemonic('s');
        viewMenu.addSeparator();
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("showhidethumb")).setMnemonic('b');
        viewMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("hide_show")).setMnemonic('a');

        JMenu imageMenu = new JMenu("Image");
        imageMenu.setMnemonic('i');
        mainMenuBar.add(imageMenu);
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("enhance")).setMnemonic('e');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("invert")).setMnemonic('v');
        imageMenu.addSeparator();
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("zoom_in")).setMnemonic('i');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("zoom_out")).setMnemonic('o');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("zoom_custom")).setMnemonic('z');
        imageMenu.addSeparator();
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("fit_height")).setMnemonic('h');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("fit_width")).setMnemonic('w');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("fit_window")).setMnemonic('o');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("fit_actualsize")).setMnemonic('a');
        imageMenu.addSeparator();
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("rotate_90")).setMnemonic('r');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("rotate_180")).setMnemonic('8');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("rotate_270")).setMnemonic('l');
        imageMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("rotate_pages")).setMnemonic('p');

        JMenu annotationMenu = new JMenu("Annotation");
        annotationMenu.setMnemonic('a');
        mainMenuBar.add(annotationMenu);
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Arrow")).setMnemonic('a');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Circle")).setMnemonic('c');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Highlight")).setMnemonic('h');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Line")).setMnemonic('l');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Note")).setMnemonic('n');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Pen")).setMnemonic('p');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Rect")).setMnemonic('r');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Stamp")).setMnemonic('s');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("Text")).setMnemonic('t');
        annotationMenu.addSeparator();
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("eraser")).setMnemonic('e');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("move_front")).setMnemonic('f');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("send_back")).setMnemonic('b');
        annotationMenu.add(myGenDocViewer.getAction("properties")).setMnemonic('o');
    }
```

I am using TViewerApplet.java (which extends JApplet) from here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.samples.doc%2Fsamples%2Fjava%2Fviewer%2Freadme.html

Browser info:: I am using Internet Explorer 8

jdk version: jdk1.6

Comment: We need more information! How are you creating/adding the menus? Is the applet publicly available? Which browsers are involved?

Comment: maybe client mode is more secure than server mode. Maybe it doesnt let you reach files.

Comment: please provide some detail like your browser, system info, jdk version... this info is not sufficient

Comment: By 'disabled' do you mean 'grayed out/cannot be selected' or 'can be selected but does nothing'?  Are you looking at the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) output?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `AbstractAction#isEnabled` for the corresponding action of a disabled menu item

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is 'grayed out/cannot be selected'.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  What about the return value, as suggested by @Robin?

Comment: @AndrewThompson,Robin  the return value of AbstractAction#isEnabled is false.

Comment: OK.. Which menu items specifically are disabled?  Add a comment to the source code line for every disabled item.  Is the applet trusted?  Is it deployed using JNLP (Java Web Start)?  Is there an URL where we can visit the applet?  I don't think @Robin was notified as to the info. that the return value was `false`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson export_doc & open_doc are disabled.Applet is not signed.It is not deployed using JNLP.I am using TViewerApplet to view scanned docs which is here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.samples.doc%2Fsamples%2Fjava%2Fviewer%2Freadme.html.

Comment: Good ! That means you can focus simply on those actions and have to check why they are disabled, as everything else seems to work as expected (disabled action results in disabled menu item)